# What is the spec that causes blocks with width to be on new lines

Tags: css, specifications

I'm not sure that I understand this aspect of `display: block`.

If I have two subsequent block elements with set widths that leave enough room for the elements so that they *could* be side-by-side it would seem like they should be side-by-side. That's not what happens though.

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
div {
 height: 100px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 display: block;
}
.left {
 background-color: blue;
}
.right {
 background-color: red;
}
.half {
 width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="half left"></div><div class="half right"></div>
```

From what I understand, there is no concept in the css layout module as a "line" so there's nothing (as w3schools says) as having "all blocks start on a new line".

So what exactly is the part of the spec that describes this behavior?

**Note:** I know there are many ways to position things side-by-side, from `inline-block`, to `float`, to `flexbox`, I'm looking for an answer that specifically describes what the spec'ed behavior is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Section 9.4.1 of CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting):

> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other, vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block.

That's actually all there is to it. To be precise, boxes that participate in a block formatting context are block-level boxes in the normal flow within that context. This includes block boxes (`display: block`), and any other block-level boxes such as `display: table` and `display: flex` (i.e. not the `inline-*` counterparts), except those that are floated or absolutely positioned as they are taken out of the flow.

The concept of "lines" mostly only pertains to inline formatting contexts, which are described in the [following section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting). You are right in that there is no concept of "lines" in a block layout *per se*.